# Prestashop : How to Empty cart?

Tags: prestashop, cart

I want to make Cart order list empty after a new product has been added to the cart.
In fact only on product every time can be in cart.
Tanx

Comment: $products = $this->getProducts();
  foreach ($products as $product) 
  {
  $this->deleteProduct($product->id);
  }

Comment: i used above code on method Add in cart.php class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 ways to add your custom logic :

- create your own module and hook it on "actionCartSave"
- <strike>override "add" and "update" methods in "Cart" class (/override/classes/Cartp.php)</strike>

Edit : The 2nd way os wrong because infinite update loop.

Here is a module that do it :

```
class OneProductCart extends Module {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->name = 'oneproductcart';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0';
        $this->author = 'SJousse';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        parent::__construct();
        $this->displayName = $this->l('One Product Cart');
        $this->description = $this->l('Keep only last product in cart.');
    }
    public function install() {
        return (parent::install() && $this->registerHook('actionCartSave'));
    }
    public function hookActionCartSave($params) {
        $cart = $params['cart'];
        $last = $cart->getLastProduct();
        $prods = $cart->getProducts();

        foreach ($prods as $prod)
            if ($prod['id_product'] != $last['id_product'])
                $cart->deleteProduct($prod['id_product']);
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to edit class : cart.php
Which function i have to use in method class?
I used fucntion deleteproduct but doesn't wotk.
pleas expain more
tanx

Comment: Try in the method Update of the Cart class instead of the Add method. If you want to remove existing products, it's an update.

Comment: i use this code in update method:
$products = $this->getProducts();
foreach ($products as $product)
{ $this->deleteProduct($product->id); }

after add to cart i get error 503 on page.

Comment: Thank you very much.
The little problem still exist is about quantity of a product.
after adding a product twice the quantity sums with previous quantity.

Comment: I try both ways but still it cause infinite loop.  because productdelete() calls Update method each time.

Comment: Did you remove the override ? I tested the module on a real shop without problem.

Comment: I solve the problem by moving code to productController.php and problem solved.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For people using Prestashop v 1.4.9 and have created a module:

call `global $smarty, $cart;`

then run the function `$cart->delete();`

```
 function hookHome($params)
    {

    global $smarty, $cart;
    /** some code here **/

    $cart->delete();

    }
```