# how to redirect after clicking Add to Cart in Prestashop

Tags: authentication, redirect, controller, prestashop, cart

Redirect to Login page after clicking to Add to Cart button

When client clicks on Add to Cart, he or she will be automatically redirect to the Login Page.

for Page redirection i got this
Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=authentication?back=my-account');

But i'm searching to past this code in some controller
please help me out or is there any solutions is there in prestashop

Answer (score 1):

go to admin panel and follow this steps:

1. Modules -> cart block -> configure -> disable ajax add to cart
2. preferences -> products -> set after product added to cart to cart summary
3. preferences -> Orders -> set order process type to "one page check-out"

Answer (score 0):

Use the module from this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14497847/1903705

And replace the content of hookActionCartSave by your redirect.

You should add some other checks (already logged in, etc.).

Comment: I Can't able to find hookActionCartSave. I just want to redirect if the cart count is not null, in FrontController.php

Comment: hookActionCartSave is a method of the module. It's called when product is added to the cart. Then you add your logic about products count.

Comment: I'm totally confused, I know how to redirecting from FrontController.php

But i'm not familar with creating new module. Can you give me the right code to redirect if the Cart Count is not null (mainly how to get the cart count value)

Comment: Please read carefully the answer I redirected you, you have all the code to do what you want. Look at the hookActionCartSave method, the current Cart object is in $params['cart'], it's a Cart class object from /classes/Cart.php.